# Rails how assign created_at in a model and / or model callback to an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, created-at

I am building an e-commerce app. I want to assign `created_at` to an attribute.

Stale `Product` inventory is 'sent' / 'submitted' to the `SaleController`, creating a product on sale.

1. I am trying to assign the time `created_at` to `sale_start_time` - an attribute of the model `Sale` - which I can later use to trigger mark-downs, for example, `@sale_start_time+5day` .  In the `Sale` model:

   ```
    def sale_start_time
        @sale.created_at
    end
   ```

That does not work, nor does `@sale_start_time = @sale.created_at` -- even though in a view, for example `sales#show`, `@sale.created_at` returns the `created_at` time.

2. I also tried placing it in a Sale model `after commit` (although I can't determine if two attributes can be changed in a single after commit). `Product` does toggle `product_on_sale: false` to `product_on_sale: true` (which, practically speaking, removes it from product inventory).  The `Sale` update of the attribute doesn't work.  It 'raises' `'id'={:id=>nil}` I'd user `Sale.find_by(@product_id)...` however, `product_id` may not equal `sale_id`.

   ```
   def update_status
      Product.find_by(@product_id).toggle!(:product_on_sale)
      Sale.find(id: @id).update(sale_start_time: @sale.created_at)
   end
   ```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can assign it in a `after_create` callback.

In the `Sale` model add this:

```rb
class Sale
  # other stuff
  after_create :assign_start_time  

  # other methods

  private

  def assign_start_time
    self.sale_start_time = created_at
    self.save!
  end
end
```

Edit by OP: This works IF the controller method `def create` defines sale as `@sale = Sale.create(sale_params)` 'create' sets the `sale id`.  I was using `@sale = Sale.new(sale_params)` which does not set the `sale id` until the transaction is committed.

Comment: Because an 'id' isn't assigned until the transaction commit, your answer did not work.  However, it pointed me in the right direction.  Please make the following changes and I'll accept it for the benefit of future searchers: (1) ```after_create_commit``` rather than ```after_create``` and (2) delete the ```def sale_start_time / self.created_at / end``` - it puts the server into an endless loop because the sale id isn't yet assigned and timestamp created

Comment: Important follow-up: My create sale action ```def create``` is using ```@sale = Sale.new(sale_params)``` -- which I just learned from another SO Q&A will NOT set the ```sale id``` / because of 'new'?  Using ```@sale = Sale.create(sale_params)``` makes the ```after_create``` method you recommended work.  The shorter approach ```def sale_start_time``` also works.

Comment: Thanks - see my notes.  Accepted your answer.